# F# - Convert a char to int

Tags: f#, functional-programming

While coding in F# for a project, I have come to a point where I want to convert a char to an int. I.e.

```
let c = '3'
c |> int //this will however give the ascii value of 3 I believe
```

My question is, what is the best way to convert a single char to an int without converting the char to a string or another types, in a case where the char only holds a digit?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you've validated the character and *know* that it's an ASCII digit, you can do the following:

```
let inline charToInt c = int c - int '0'

let c = '3'
c |> charToInt
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://rextester.com/JBUZE88080)**</kbd>

N.b. if you ultimately need a `float` rather than an `int` there is a built-in mechanism: [`System.Char.GetNumericValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx)

Comment: I think I will stick with the `System.Char.GetNumericValue` and piping it to `int`. Thanks.

Comment: ```c |> System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetDigitValue```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to convert a -> 0, b -> 1, ....., z -> 26. Then you could do this

```
let let2nat (letter : char) = int letter - int 'a'
```

If you just want the ascii you can do this

```
let let2ascii (let2ascii : char) = int let2ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of minutes ago I had the same problem but I got resolved with this 2 ways

1. `int (string valueChar)`
2. `int (Char.GetNumericValue valueChar)`

knowing that valueChar is '5' or similar and you wanna the int value

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string first:

```
'1' |> System.Char.ToString |> int
```

Comment: let c = '1'

let str = c |>Char.ToString

int str